# How to fix a messy GRUB config with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, multi-boot, grub

This is my set up - I have an SSD with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15 dual booted, and an additional HDD which I use for extra data.

Every so often I will get this error when selecting Windows 10 from the GRUB menu:

```
Setting partition type to 0x7

A disk read error occurred
Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart
```

Sometimes the error disappears and I'm able to to boot into Windows 10 easily. Sometimes it persists. Sometimes I'll boot into ubuntu, restart and am able to jump into Windows 10 again. Sometimes I'll go into Ubuntu, change the order of the OSes on my GRUB menu via GRUB Configurator (or is it customizer?) and that seems to work - at least it did, but that half-baked solution doesn't seem to yield any results anymore.

I should not that when my system was a single OS rig with just Windows 8, I would sometimes get this error without the "Setting partition type to 0x7" prefixing it.

The way I see it, I have three options:

1. Try to fix GRUB so I don't have to deal with these issues anymore.
2. Try to find a way to restore Windows 10 bootloader and get rid of ubuntu (I need Windows 10 more). If that's the case, how would I do that? And could I reclaim the same I gave to ubuntu to windows?
3. Just do a system reset and reformat my drives and put windows 10 on the SSD, by itself.

Any thoughts?